# Leetcode. twoSum скорость выполнения и объем памяти

Tags: python

Всем доброго дня
Начал решать задачи на leetcode. Самая первая задача twoSum. Два схожих решения, но скорость выполнения и объем занимаемой памяти отличаются

1. ```python
   class Solution(object):
       def twoSum(self, nums, target):
           compliment = {}
           for i,num in enumerate(nums):
               key = target - num
               if key in compliment:
                   return [i,nums.index(key)]
               compliment[num] = target - num
   ```

   У данного решения runtime 40 ms и объем памяти 14.2 mb
2. ```python
   class Solution(object):
       def twoSum(self, nums, target):
           compliment = {}
           for i,num in enumerate(nums):
               key = target - num
               if key in compliment:
                   return [i,compliment[key]]
               compliment[num] = i
   ```

   А у данного решения runtime 48 ms и объем памяти 14.4 mb

Данная разница возникает за счет того, что время обращения к объектам словаря больше чем к объектам массива?

Comment: Словно должно быть наоборот, так как `nums.index(key)` имеет сложность `O(n)`, в то время как `compliment[key]` имеет сложность `O(1)`

Comment: Вы на метрики литкода смотрите? А вы одно и то же решение попробуйте несколько раз сдать и оценить разброс.

Comment: Смотреть на время выполнения не литкоде имеет смысл только если оно в разы отличается от среднего по больнице. А так просто там разброс по времени одного и того же решения зависит от кучи факторов.